# Ubuntu USB dongle

Tags: usb

I have recently installed Ubuntu on my PC that I have built. My mother board does not have wireless network card so I bought a CSL USB 2.0 Dual Band WLAN Adapter. I have got the driver disc and extracted them onto my PC but I don't know how to install them on Ubuntu. 
please help.

Here is the link for the usb dongle...
https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B015Z8JAYS/ref=s9_simh_gw_p23_d0_i1?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=desktop-1&pf_rd_r=26F1BADJA75ZG5YGZDZF&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=867551807&pf_rd_i=desktop

Here is the screen shots for the drivers:

[image]

Comment: You might maybe add the names of the friver files you have extracted onto your disk.

Comment: No I extrated them onto my desktop

Comment: @DanielTrion Please link to the adapter! And please provide a screenshot of the extracted files... more information is needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can't install Windows drivers in Ubuntu.

If [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/high-performance-gold-plated-technology-Frequency-adjustable/dp/B00PKABAI6?ie=UTF8&*Version*=1&*entries*=0) is the adapter you're referring too, you shouldn't need to do anything other than just plug it in.

Comment: That is not the dongle I am using I have opened the files on the disc called Linux but I  don't know what to do now because unlike in windows there is no dart up or install file